# Sublime Text 3 Code autoformatting

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've searched high and low, but I can't seem to find a plugin that makes Sublime work similar to how Visual Studio formats my code as I type it.

For example, when *I* write a `for` loop, it looks something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<value.length;i++) {
    //loop body
}
```

As soon as I complete the loop body, Visual Studio will format it to be much more readable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
{
    //loop body
}
```

Basically, it's just adding spaces around operators in this case, but it does much more.  If I write horribly indented HTML/XML code, it corrects the indentation.  Arrays and multiline conditionals become much more readable.

Are there any Sublime Text 3 plugins out there that do something similar to this?  Everybody seems to highly recommend the "Reindent" command, which works for the HTML/XML formatting, but it doesn't space everything out in a consistent way.  [JsParen](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) looks good, but it won't work for any other language that I use, namely PHP, and it's for ST2.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[CodeFormatter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CodeFormatter) is one possible option for PHP. It uses the PEAR [PHP_Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier), which you'll need to install separately. There are a bunch of configuration options detailed in the README, so you should be able to find something that suits your needs.

For C/C++/C#/Java code, you can't go wrong with [SublimeAStyleFormatter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeAStyleFormatter), a formatter that uses the popular AStyle rules. Again, there are many options available, check the `.sublime-settings` file for details.

[HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) is what I'm using currently for those languages. It requires node.js to work, so make sure you read through the instructions carefully.

Finally, you may think I'm being facetious, but I'm really not: pay attention to style when you're coding. I work a lot in Python, where the visual presentation of the code is actually part of the syntax. Code is meant to be read, by other developers as well as by machines, and it does no one any good to try and pound out poorly-formatted, unindented code while thinking "I'll just prettify it later." Maybe your formatter doesn't fix all your mistakes, or maybe you forget, or get lazy. If you focus on the look and structure of the code, you can more easily see how the different parts fit together, and perhaps catch some bugs before they can do any harm. Set a clear style guide for yourself, and stick with it. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Very good advice all around.  I don't write unreadable blobs of code, I mainly wanted something to follow standards and fix minor mistakes like forgetting a space between the condition and the `if`.  CodeFormatter is working fantastically for me, thank you very much!

Comment: Why cant sublime just have a short key for these things. Why does all answers for sublime simple functions run into paragraphs of explainations. Seriously!!1

Comment: @Siddharth You need to download plugins for lightweight text editors such as Sublime Text. They're not IDEs with all the bells and whistles built in. vim is perhaps even more notorious in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

- Open Sublime Text editor.
- Press Ctrl + Shift + P.
- In the menu select Package Control : install Package
- Now select SublimeAStyleFormatter.

After installing the above extension, you may press **Ctrl + Alt + F** to format your current file.